# UI5: accessing DOM ref of a view after rendering during each navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I have two UI5 XML views and the navigation has been implemented between both the views. Whenever I visit the second view, I manipulate the HTML DOM (using jQuery and CSS) to do some look and feel related changes which is not readily available in UI5 by default.

**My issue is:** When I wrote jQuery code to manipulate DOM in `(route)patternMatched` handler of second view, it is not working as DOM does not exist at that point. When I put the jQuery code in **`onAfterRendering()`** of second view, it **gets executed only during first visit** so not giving the desired result during 2nd visit onwards.

Can you tell me how to get rid of this issue or what design change I should make here?

Also, do we have any setting in UI5 by which `onAfterRendering()` will be called every time when I navigate to a view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["onBeforeRendering" or "onAfterRendering" is not called every time the view is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082731/onbeforerendering-or-onafterrendering-is-not-called-every-time-the-view-is-o)

Comment: > _When I wrote jQuery code to manipulate DOM in `(route)patternMatched` handler of second view, it is not working as DOM does not exist at that point._ ... I can't reproduce it. Here you can see that it's accessible there: https://embed.plnkr.co/wp6yes?show=controller/Next.controller.js,preview. For other solutions, see the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55099341/5846045) in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onBeforeShow` method to do the manipulations required by you.

The `onBeforeShow` will be called every time the view is about to be shown to the screen.

But first you have to attach the event to the view in onInit. 
Code:

```
onInit : function () {
    this.getView().addEventDelegate({
        onBeforeShow : jQuery.proxy(function(evt) {
            this.onBeforeShow(evt);
        }, this)
    });
},

onBeforeShow: function() {

    console.log('called from on Before show');
    // DO manipulation here
}
```

If, you still don't find the DOM elements in this event handler, remember `onBeforeShow` has a sister: `onAfterShow` which will be called after the view is shown on screen.

API Link : [NavContainerChild](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.NavContainerChild)

Comment: Hi Rahul,

Thanks for your input.
Your solution did the job for me. It worked fine with onAfterShow() :)
I am wondering why this information is not present in sapui5 documentation.. Or is it such that I missed it!!??

Also, can you please differentiate between 
onAfterRendering() and onAfterShow()?